# In 'getTreeCellRendererComponent' what does 'int row' do?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm making a treeCellRenderer for a program, and I'm looking at the documentation for [getTreeCellRendererComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeCellRenderer.html). Even looking at the example, [DefaultTreeCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellRenderer.html) it isn't clear: **What does `int row` do?**

Even some of the [examples](http://naveedmurtuza.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/display-xml-in-jtree-with-dnd-support.html) I found on the web doen't use it. Does anyone use it? How should I implement it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It contains the number of the row this Renderer is called for. So you can render the component dependent on the row number. You might want to implement alternating row colors this way.

Try to set a breakpoint in that method and see how the value of `row` behaves.

Comment: But...how does it know the row if I have part-collapsed tree?

Comment: It knows your data model, it doesn't care about what you are doing in the UI.

Comment: @Pureferret a row in a tree is visible by definition, so it can't be under a collapsed node :-) Well-behaved clients should not rely on whatever its value is, well-behaved renderer implementation should cope with nonsense for that value (core ui is notorious in passing in "hidden rows" that is rows that would be valid if the node where expanded but is collapsed, thus pointed to another row than was meant or entirely outside of the tree)